# In a metric space $X$ suppose $\exists y,z$ s.t. $d(x,y)=1, d(x,z)=2,$ but $\nexists w\in X$ s.t. $d(x,w)=3/2$. Prove $X$ is disconnected.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, metric-spaces, connectedness

This was a homework problem for a point-set topology course.

Let $X$ be a metric space with metric $d$, and let $x\in X.$ Suppose there exist $y,z\in X$ with $d(x,y)=1$ and $d(x,z)=2,$ but there exists no $w\in X$ with $d(x,w)=3/2.$ Prove $X$ is not connected.

Proof. We claim that the ball $B_{3/2}(x)$ is both closed and open in $X$ but is neither empty, nor $X$ itself. Since $x\in B_{3/2}(x)$ therefore $B_{3/2}(x)\neq \emptyset$ and since $d(x,z)>3/2$ the point $z\notin B_{3/2}(x)$ so $B_{3/2}(x)\neq X.$ Next, clearly $B_{3/2}(x)$ is open so it suffices to also show $B_{3/2}(x)$ is closed. Let $y\in X\setminus B_{3/2}(x).$ Then by definition $d(x,y)\geq 3/2,$ but since there exist no $w\in X$ with $d(x,w)=3/2$ it must be that $d(x,y)> 3/2.$ Set $\delta=\frac 12 d(x,y)-\frac 32,$ and then $\delta>0$ with $B_\delta (y) \subset X\setminus B_{3/2}(x).$ Hence $X\setminus B_{3/2}(x)$ is open, so $B_{3/2}(x)$ is closed and $X$ is not connected. $\Box$

Is this correct?

Comment: Your proof is correct. Trust yourself! In my opinion writing an official answer to questions like this is a rather thankless task - if there is no error in the proof, one cannot write much more than "yes". I suggest if you have doubts in your proofs, explain what precisely makes you feel uncertain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Briefly, yes, that sounds perfect!

Another way to look at it: the function $f: t \mapsto d(x, t)$ is continuous. So $X - B_{3/2}(x) = f^{-1}(3/2, \infty)$ is open, just as $B_{3/2}(x) = f^{-1}[0, 3/2)$ is open. So that gives you a disconnection.